# JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and Log4j + Not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, log4j

In my pom.xml, I added below dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

And as suggested in jboss forum, i added below jboss-deployment-structure.xml under WEB-INF in war project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
   <deployment>
     <exclusions>  
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
     </exclusions>  
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But still server log is print, no application logs in my console.

My log4j.properties in classpath has below setting.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender, fileAppender

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${jboss.server.base.dir}/log/wm/sample.log
```

Console log what i am getting is below

```
09:35:36,122 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015850: /C:/Mohan/Software/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/wm.ear/wm-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml in subdeployment ignored. jboss-deployment-structure.xml is only parsed for top level deployments.
```

Can somebody help me in pointing what am i missing in the above set?

**Edit:**

Structure of my application is - Each will have its own pom.xml and parent will have common pom.xml. I have added all slf4j related dependency in war pom.xml.

parent (pom.xml)
  |
  |__ear (pom.xml)
  |
  |__war (pom.xml)
  |
  |__test (pom.xml)

Comment: Could you please update your question with the structure of your application?

Comment: @aribeiro - Sorry for delay response. I have added structure of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring you can configure your log4j from the web.xml

```
  <!-- Logging listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:yourpath/log4j.properties</param-value>
    <!-- You can also define yourpath with a environment variable and use it like file:${env_variable_path}/log4j.properties  -->
  </context-param>
```

Also, if you are still having problems you can you try with theese exclusions in your jboos-deployment-structure.xml

```
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
    </exclusions>
```

I think you need to overide other logging mechanisms.

Comment: I tried with these both, but still no luck. Yes somehow that jboss logging and application logging is getting conflict. That's what they suggested us to add jboss-deployment-structure.xml to excluded their logging. But still something is missing.

Comment: When JBoss boots you should be able to see something like this: 16:25:41,438 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApp]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Initializing log4j from [file:/yourpath/log4j.properties], if not probably log4j is not booting. If you can see it maybe there is a config problem on your properties.

Comment: Yes, i am seeing that line while booting. Same code, if i run in Wildfly9, it is working properly.

Comment: So, it seems that there is a problem with your properties file. Can you put only this in a new log4j.properties file ?: log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  Sometimes log4j does not work properly because of a malformed file because of an invalid BOM or strange encoding.

Comment: I use Spring on JBoss and tried adding both tags to web.xml and it kinda worked for the first time, seeing the "Initializing log4" in JBoss console and creating my custom log file in jbossdir/bin/myfile.log, but empty for now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, wouldn't setting `<scope>provided</scope>` in your war's pom do just fine?

Anyway, from the log you get I can see you deploy the war as part of ear archive. You need to reflect the fact in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
To find out how refer to [JBoss AS7 docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7), or documentation of whatever JBoss server you use.

Just an overview:You put your jboss-deployment-structure.xml into the ear archive. In the xml you have to define the war's configuration as subdeployment:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
   <deployment>
      ....
   </deployment>
   <sub-deployment name="wm-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
   </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```